# How to add a new attribute to an existing LDAP objectclass?

Tags: ldap, openldap, edirectory

I created a custom LDAP objectClass, but forgot a couple attributes before I added it to my OpenLDAP server. I followed the instructions on this Ubuntu doc page: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openldap-server.html I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

So, how do I add a new MAY attribute to an objectClass that is already applied to the server?

Specifically on OpenLDAP, but it would be good to know how for Novell eDirectory as well.

Comment: Just tried this ldif file:

version: 1

dn: cn={4}lccperson,cn=schema,cn=config
add: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.32916.2.1.1.1.29 NAME 'lccPersonMiddleName' DESC 'The persons middle name.' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )

And that apparently added the gibberish in the next comment.

Comment: olcAttributeTypes:: ezI4fSggMS4zLjYuMS40LjEuMzI5MTYuMi4xLjEuMS4yOSBOQU1FICdsY2NQZXJzb25NaWRkbGVOYW1lJyBERVNDICdUaGUgcGVyc29ucyBtaWRkbGUgbmFtZS4nIEVRVUFMSVRZIGNhc2VJZ25vcmVNYXRjaCBTVUJTVFIgY2FzZUlnbm9yZVN1YnN0cmluZ3NNYXRjaCAJU1lOVEFYIDEuMy42LjEuNC4xLjE0NjYuMTE1LjEyMS4xLjE1IFNJTkdMRS1WQUxVRSAp

Hmm... Comments don't format well do they. 

Anyway, any suggestions?

Comment: moral of the story, avoid tabs in your ldif file.

Comment: You're able to edit your original question. You can insert the formatted comments as part of the question and delete the comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The short answer

Use ldapmodify exactly like you would on a regular ldap entry with multi-valued attributes.

That's pretty much what I expected, but I wasn't 100% sure, due to the {N} indexing that you see when you run an ldap search for the schema.

### The long answer

First, find your schema's dn. Something like cn={4}test,cn=schema,cn=config
Then write an ldif file and apply it to your directory. On Ubuntu 12.04 I applied it as root with:

```
ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi://  -f test.ldif
```

The part I had issues with was the ldif modify syntax, and what to do with the {N} indexes.

So, the start of your ldif file should be something like:

```
version: 1

dn: cn={N}test,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
```

To modify an objectClass:

```
delete: olcObjectClasses
olcObjectClasses: <old value>
-
add: olcObjectClasses
olcObjectClasses: <new value>
```

To modify an attribute:

```
delete: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: <old value>
-
add: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: <new value>
```

Some tips I figured out about syntax:

- Ignore the {N} indexes in your ldif file. They get fixed automatically.
- You do need the {N} in your schema's DN.
- Remember the '**-**' between statements.
- Don't put a new line after the '**-**'. ldapmodify stops at that new line, so anything after it will not be executed.
- Add new attributes before you modify the objectClass to include them.
- Eliminate all tab characters. They cause the system to produce gibberish.

Comment: will this work to add without deleting 1st?